# T-SQL: Check temperature over 24 hour period

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a SQL Server database with two values I'm interested in:

```
dtime - datetime
temperature - varchar
```

The table is fed by an external process that takes a building's temperature every 30 minutes. I'm interested in triggering an alert if the temperature exceeds 80 degrees for 48 periods (24 hours).

I think this needs to be an external process that scans the table and sends an alert when this condition is met. I'm struggling with writing the SQL to do this.

**EDIT**

The data I'm pulling in comes in on a weekly basis. During this week I need to see if at any time in a 24-hour period the temperature has exceeded 80 degrees. The air conditioning could fail at any time and span two days or more, so I need to potentially check this across multiple days. The temperature is taken every half hour, so during the week I need to check if there are 48+ instances where the temperature exceeded 80 degrees.

Sample data:

```
10/1/2012 12:00:00 AM | 70 | {ok}
10/1/2012 12:30:00 AM | 70 | {ok}
10/1/2012 1:00:00 AM | 70 | {ok}
10/1/2012 1:30:00 AM | 75 | {ok}
10/1/2012 2:00:00 AM | 75 | {ok}
10/1/2012 2:30:00 AM | 80 | {ok}
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data. It is odd to use `varchar` for numeric data.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Have a look at [Notification Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166495(v=sql.90).aspx)

Comment: Are missed samples an issue, or do you have flawless data collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ALL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543.aspx):

```
IF 80 < ALL(
  SELECT temperature 
  FROM (
    SELECT temperature, dtime,
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dtime DESC)
    FROM dbo.Temps 
  ) X
  WHERE RN <= 48
)
SELECT 'ALERT, the last 48 measurements exceeded 80 degrees!'
ELSE 
SELECT 'everything is okay';
```

Fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e2c8/7/0

Edit:  As Blam has mentioned this can be simplified by using `TOP`

```
IF 80 < ALL(
   SELECT TOP 48 temperature 
   FROM dbo.Temps
   ORDER BY dtime DESC
)
SELECT 'ALERT, the last 48 measurements exceeded 80 degrees!'
ELSE 
SELECT 'everything is okay';
```

Comment: +1 but I think you can simpify IF 80 <= ALL( SELECT top 48 temperature FROM dbo.Temps ORDER BY dtime DESC)

Answer (score 3):

```
select 'alert'
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from MyTable
    where dtime > dateadd(day, -1, getdate())
        and cast(temperature as int) <= 80
)
```

Comment: To explain, this query checks to see if there are any temperatures below 80 degrees in a 24 hour period.  If not, then the  temperatures were all above 80 and the alert should be sent.

Comment: You may want to add a check to make sure there are ANY records returned during the last 24 hrs just for a sanity check.